# Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: apache, cakephp

I'm getting the following error in my CakePHP application:

Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://projectname.dev/

My .htaccess in the root folder, looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and in the app folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

and in the webroot folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /projectname
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I was following this tutorial:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I just found a solution to the problem here:

https://willcodeforcoffee.com/cakephp/2007/01/31/cakephp-error-500-too-many-redirects.html

The .htaccess file in webroot should look like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

instead of this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /projectname
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: for cake 2.4.1, the .htaccess is the one in the folder which contains app, lib, plugins, vendor; not the app/webroot.  also the one important change is to add the `RewriteBase /`... the other parts of the .htaccess may not match and that is fine.

Comment: Great solution yaar... I happens in my codeigniter, centos 6 environment, thanks.

Comment: How would you fix this for Windows

Comment: I can confirm as of 1/23/2016 that this works. Thanks. My .htaccess was previously: 

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: I just had to un-comment this line 'RewriteBase /' in my .htaccess , thx u!!

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me, you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Worked like a charm for me
Windows 10 / Wampp / Yii2 
I set up it as advanced local website

Answer (score 10):

```
//Just add 

RewriteBase /
//after 
RewriteEngine On

//and you are done....

//so it should be 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

i solved this by
<strike>http://willcodeforcoffee.com/2007/01/31/cakephp-error-500-too-many-redirects/</strike>
just uncomment or add this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

to your .htaccess file

Comment: Dead link. No coffee?

Comment: i'm going to take some

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred to me when I was debugging the PHP [header](http://php.net/header)() function:

```
header('Location: /aaa/bbb/ccc'); // error
```

If I use a relative path it works:

```
header('Location: aaa/bbb/ccc'); // success, but not what I wanted
```

However when I use an absolute path like `/aaa/bbb/ccc`, it gives the exact error:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
>   configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the
>   limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

It appears the header function redirects internally without going HTTP at all which is weird. After some tests and trials, I found the solution of adding exit after header():

```
header('Location: /aaa/bbb/ccc');
exit;
```

And it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

Following the cakePHP official documentation, the .htaccess should be like this:

https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/installation/url-rewriting.html

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply removing the rewrite base in the internal .htaccess file fixed mine .
like a had an htaccess file in my root directory simply linking to an index page in the public directory which is in my root folder then i had another htaccess file rewriting each request to the index page in that same public folder , and removing the RewriteBase fixe mine .  as shown below

this is the first .htaccess file in the root
directory

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In our codeigniter with apache environment, we need to add .htaccess at to root level of application. Below is the .htaccess content;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```