# Laravel Vagrant - Inernal server error

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

I am working on a Laravel Project with Vagrant. I access my project using this URL: localhost:8081

But recently, when I run "Vagrant up" and try to access through my browser, it says "Internal Server Error".

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

The only thing I'm suspicious of causing this problem is the following: 
My torrent client was crashing constantly and I entered the following command to fix my torrent from crashing: "netsh interface teredo set state disabled" (Found this solution on the net)

When I see vagrant ssh into my VM and cd into /var/log/apache2 and open error.log, I get the following:

```
[Sat Feb 15 11:17:47.144253 2014] [core:error] [pid 924] [client 10.0.2.2:51189] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Sat Feb 15 11:17:51.706669 2014] [core:error] [pid 922] [client 10.0.2.2:51190] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Kindly help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution a few weeks after I posted this. Apache on Debian/Ubuntu got updated around the time I posted this question and the doc root changed to /var/www/html instead of /var/www. So I had to change the sym link in the vagrant file to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect your .htaccess or virtual host configuration.

Try to remove them and access with absolute URL.

If it won't help, check your php.ini file for errors.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error log report:

> [Sat Feb 15 11:17:47.144253 2014] [core:error] [pid 924] [client
>   10.0.2.2:51189] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use
>   'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use
>   'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

This is an internal server error and it's most probably because of any invalid `Mod_Rewrite` rules in `.htaccess` file which may create a `redirect loop`.

Can't assist specifically but [this](http://www.andrew-kirkpatrick.com/2012/06/apache-virtualhost-htaccess-issue-request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects-redirected-from-r-uri/) may give you some idea and these answers ([equest-exceeded...1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850845/request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects-due-to-probable-configuratio) and [request-exceeded...2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611506/request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects-due-to-probable-configuratio)) on so could be helpful too.