# Installing laravel 5 in sub-directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5, httpd.conf

I wanted to isntall laravel in a sub directory inside my dev machine http://dev-machine/applis/main/laravel

My default document root is F:/data/web

My .htaccess file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /applis/main/laravel
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

My httpd.conf file has below code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName http://dev-machine/applis/main/laravel/public
  DocumentRoot F:/data/web/applis/main/laravel/public
  <Directory "applis/main/laravel/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also tried the belwo virtual host config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName http://dev-machine/applis/main/laravel/public
  Alias /laravel applis/main/laravel/public
  DocumentRoot F:/data/web/applis/main/laravel/public
  <Directory "/applis/main/laravel/public">
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But stil I am unable to access the app via

```
http://dev-machine/applis/main/laravel/public
```

I am getting he below error

```
Not Found

The requested URL /applis/main/laravel/public/ was not found on this server.
```

After adding the virtual host when it is not even loading the index.php file when I try loading it directly via http://dev-machine/applis/main/laravel/public/index.php

Comment: Have you updated your host file?

Comment: Yes, I have. and still it is the same. :-(

Comment: I edited my Document root to /applis/main/laravel/public removing the F:/applis/main and nwo I am getting the error that says access is Forbidden, please help

Comment: Is there any laravel setup in F:/data/web? or do you have any .htaccess file in F:/data/web?

Comment: Can you try adding like as shown in virtualhost and restart your local server? [Note down full path in directory] <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName http://dev-machine/applis/main/laravel/public
  DocumentRoot F:/data/web/applis/main/laravel/public
  <Directory "F:/data/web/applis/main/laravel/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Laravel instalation is inside Laravel folder in F:\data\web\applis\main\laravel and not in the F:/data/web... and I have the .htaccess file inside public directory fo the laravel folder

Comment: On changing it and restarting the server, I got Internal server error, then on checking the logs I have the below  `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: Can you please paste the .htaccess file content in question or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850845/request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects-due-to-probable-configuratio might this be useful to you..

Comment: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: I think it is working now, THanks for the help

Comment: Please share your answer with community..

Comment: I have to use the ocrrect virtual host setting that you asked me to use.`<VirtualHost *:80> ServerName dev-machine/applis/main/laravel/public DocumentRoot F:/data/web/applis/main/laravel/public <Directory "F:/data/web/applis/main/laravel/public"> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks AllowOverride All Require all granted </Directory> </VirtualHost>` Then restarted the server and all is fine.