# How can I resolve the Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects issue (rather specific htaccess file)?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mamp

I'm setting up a local environment via MAMP of a site that I took down off the web a couple of months back in order to view some old functions on the site, and I am currently receiving the following error in my apache_error.log file.

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to     increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://localhost:8888/
```

I have looked for solutions in other posts (e.g.
[Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850845/request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects-due-to-probable-configuratio)), and I know it has to do with my .htaccess file. However, I have been unable to figure out what is wrong due to my file being rather specific. Here it is (I changed my website name to example.com for sake of privacy):

```
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^demo/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ example/public/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example/public/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^public/.*$ example/public/index.php [NC,L]
```

This might be a longshot, but if anyone can take a look and offer an idea of what might be causing the error, I'd be forever grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this with a lot of RewriteRules in my `.htaccess` file. The most straightforward thing to do is to add a line in the `.conf` file for that domain/site to increase the limit, as 10 is a bit tight. Use `LimitInternalRecursion` followed by a higher number.

For example, I have two sites they have:

`LimitInternalRecursion 100` (one site with a lot of blocking rules)

`LimitInternalRecursion 500` (an ajax-heavy SSL site with a lot of redirects to force things to do https instead of http)

A good rule of thumb is the more RewiteRules the higher the number, especially if your RewriteRules are doing a lot of blocking.

If you're still looking to trim your RewritesRules down, I'd go with (for Apache 2.2):

`<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|phps|psd|log|sh|eye)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>`

(`Require all denied` for Apache 2.4)

instead of `RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]` to protect .htaccess and other files (e.g. .ini, .log, .psd, .sh, .eye, etc.). This gives you more flexibility to block additional files.

**UPDATE:**

While reading Apache docs today for something else, I learned that `LimitInternalRecursion` will take two number values, the first number for the maximum number of redirects, the second for "how deeply subrequests may be nested" (read up on [LimitInternalRecursion](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitinternalrecursion)), something like:

`LimitInternalRecursion 100 20`

will better tune the directive.

With only one number present, Apache assumes that number for both values, so:

`LimitInternalRecursion 500`

will be read by Apache as:

`LimitInternalRecursion 500 500`

which is a little extreme ...